# Time complexity: using Givens and Householder to bring vectors into the form $(*,0)^T$

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-complexity

There are several examples in our book where we are supposed to transform vectors into scalar multiples of the first unit vector using either Givens-rotations or Householder reflections.

What is the time complexity of these methods, respectively? Can we use results for the time-complexity of Q-R decomposition using Givens or Householder somehow (they both lie in $O(nm^2)$?

Comment: What happens when $m=1$?

Comment: @CarlChristian Then we have $O(n)$, is it really as simple as that?

Comment: Yes and no. Technically, we cannot really derive the $O(nm^2)$ result without analyzing the case of $m=1$ first. Instead I suggest that you investigate the case of $m=1$ using fairly small values of of $n$ which you can do completely by hand. It is clear that a Given's rotation has constant cost and that $n-1$ rotations are need to nullify $n-1$ entries. Write down the formula for computing an Householder reflector.